# Status strip in .NET4 Forms application turns black when resing window via remote desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-desktop, statusstrip

This is the most bizarre thing we have ever come across.

We are developing a Windows forms application in C# with Visual Studio 2010. The main form contains a status strip control docked at the bottom.

When we run our application via remote desktop or via VNC server, the status strip turns into a black box as soon as the application window gets resized or maximized.

We are really out of ideas so any suggestion will be most welcome.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d30f39db-a5d4-4044-9cc3-316eab5ac4a9/toolstripstatuslabel-blacking-out-or-missing?forum=winforms) post?

Answer (score 1):

it was only by pure chance that we found it.

Our form contained an onResize event that looked like this

```
    private void FormMain_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // blah, blah 


        // have the status bar refresh itself
        statusStrip.Refresh();            
    }
```

This worked as long as the app was run on a "normal" machine. Remote desktop or access via VNC on a virtual machine turned the statusStrip into a black box on first resize.

For ... religious reasons known only to big Bill himself, switching `statusStrip.Refresh();` to `statusStrip.Invalidate();` did it.